# Unable to restore bluetooth state on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth

I have been trying for weeks to figure out how state preservation and restoration works for Core Bluetooth in iOS, but I am completely lost.

So far I have done the following:

Added a Restoration Identifier to my CBCentralManager

```
        centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil   options:@{CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey:@"myCentralManager"}];
```

Which should make my application able to call the delegate method:

```
centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
  willRestoreState:(NSDictionary *)dict;
```

In here I am trying to reconnect to my peripheral, if I had a connection prior to the app being suspended, otherwise I will try to scan for my peripheral again, like so:

```
if (dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey]) {
    for (CBPeripheral *currentPeripheral in peripherals) {
        peripheral = currentPeripheral;
    }
    // Connect to peripheral
}
else{
    // Scan for UUID
}
```

Am I doing this right, am I close, or is this completely wrong?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, not able to figure out if my code is working or not in willRestoreState method.

Comment: I added an answer, which works for me, and I hope it will work for you, as well :)

Also, for testing whether it works or not, you can make use of this
kill(getpid(), SIGKILL);
to simulate your application getting killed by the OS :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me now.
I initialize my central manager, just like I did originally, and then in the willRestoreState method, I run the following code:

```
NSArray* peripherals = [central retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:UUID]];
if ([peripherals count] > 0) {
    _discoveredPeripheral = [peripherals objectAtIndex:0];
    _discoveredPeripheral.delegate= self;
    [central connectPeripheral:_discoveredPeripheral options:nil];
} else {
[self scan];
}
```

Comment: Hi @newbiesovs, In willRestoreState, I am also abe to get the retrieved peripherals but unable to connect to all the peripherals, As per the apple document we have only 10 sec to perform the task when the app gets launched in the background. Due to which unable to complete a task to connect more than one peripherals in system given time. Have you faced the same problem? Do you have any comment on that? It will be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your code project? I'm having similar issues. Thanks!!